# programmatically change the default scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I programmatically change the default scene in Unity?

Currently, I'm only able to change the default scene via the Unity editor...

I want to change default scene so that the next time the user enters the app it load another scene.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/change-the-default-scene.340706/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set, as the initial scene, an empty one, that just loads another scene (based on a previously saved value) as soon as it starts. As an example, you can retrieve this value using PlayerPrefs, as it:

```
void Start(){
    int defaultLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("defaultLevel");
    Application.LoadLevel(defaultLevel);
}
```

Comment: How do we assign `defaultLevel` to a specific scene?

Comment: You have to invoke PlayerPrefs.SetInt("defaultLevel", X), where X is the scene's index. I suggest to search for PlayerPrefs' documentation, they are really easy to understand. (here for help: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html). By the way, a PlayerPref's value is "universal" for the entire project, and not related to a particular scene. They are stored in the OS's registry.

Comment: OK, great. Let me see this and inform you tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(0); //Use scene index
SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneName"); //Use scene name
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Make sure to add the scenes to the **Build Settings** before trying the code above.

Comment: I don't understand how this changes the default scene. Can you explain further?

Comment: @Gog65 You don't change the default scene, that makes no sense. You load new scenes.

Comment: I think loading a new scene is what the OP meant. @Go65 at the start of the game, if you DONT want the current scene to load, you can put this script in the Awake function and it will instead load another scene automatically. Isn't that what you want? If not, then explain more.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson You both don't understand. I want to change default scene so that the next time the user enters the app it load another scene!